# Text input does check on leave field does not work while other fields work. Why

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I have several inputs that are generated in my controller. Also the related javascripts are generated in the controller. The image below shows the inputs.

[image: Input sample]

The idea is that if I leave any of the controls and the control is empty, then under it it will show a message. All controls except for the first one (which is an input text) are working. I can't figure out why the first one is not working. Any sugggestions?

Below is the html and javascript.
Text control:

```html
<input 
  onfocusout="ControlId1()" 
  id="ControlId1" 
  data-val="true" 
  name="ProcessFields[0].StringValue" 
  ejs-for="true" 
  class="e-control e-textbox e-lib e-input" 
  type="text"
  role="textbox"
  value=""
>
```

Dropdown control:

```
<select aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" class="e-ddl-hidden" name="ProcessFields[2].StringValue" id="ControlId32_hidden" data-val="true"><option selected="" value="">null</option></select>
<input onfocusout="ControlId32()" id="ControlId32" data-val="true" ejs-for="true" class="e-control e-dropdownlist e-lib e-input" role="textbox" type="text" readonly="" style="" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="undefined" tabindex="-1">
```

Part of Javascript for 2 controls:

```js
function ControlId1() {
  var x = document.getElementById('ControlId1');
  console.log(x);
  if (x.value === '') {
    document.getElementById('ControlIdWarningId1').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('ControlIdWarningId1').style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function ControlId32() {
  var x = document.getElementById('ControlId32');
  console.log(x);
  if (x.value === '') {
    document.getElementById('ControlIdWarningId32').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('ControlIdWarningId32').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

The two elements for showing the message are:

```
<div class="bg-danger" style="display:none" id="ControlIdWarningId1">a</div>
<div class="bg-danger" style="display: block;" id="ControlIdWarningId32">6</div>
```

----UPDATE---
When I open the page Iget the following information in teh console (not exactly clear what to do with it). Further, when I leave the textbox control, dropdown, and richtexteditor I get 3 more messages (also below).

When open the page:

```
Some messages have been moved to the Issues panel.
jquery.min.js:2 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
w._evalUrl @ jquery.min.js:2
Re @ jquery.min.js:2
append @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
z @ jquery.min.js:2
html @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
u @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
load (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
w.fn.load @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ 1:16
e @ jquery.min.js:2
t @ jquery.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
c @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
fire @ jquery.min.js:2
c @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
ready @ jquery.min.js:2
B @ jquery.min.js:2
VM439:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at <anonymous>:6:24
    at m (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Re (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.append (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
    at z (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.html (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ VM439:6
m @ jquery.min.js:2
Re @ jquery.min.js:2
append @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
z @ jquery.min.js:2
html @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
u @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
load (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
w.fn.load @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ 1:16
e @ jquery.min.js:2
t @ jquery.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
c @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
fire @ jquery.min.js:2
c @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
ready @ jquery.min.js:2
B @ jquery.min.js:2
```

When I leave the textbox:
1:73 Uncaught TypeError: ControlId1 is not a function
at HTMLInputElement.onfocusout (1:73)
onfocusout @ 1:73

And on dropdown (which is actually working):

```
<input onfocusout="ControlId32()" id="ControlId32" data-val="true" ejs-for="true" class="e-control e-dropdownlist e-lib e-input" role="textbox" type="text" readonly="" style="" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="undefined" tabindex="-1">
```

and richtext editor(which is also working:

```
1:111 Uncaught TypeError: ControlId3 is not a function
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.onfocusout (1:111)
    at Af (VM651 ej2.min.js:10)
    at t.blurHandler (VM651 ej2.min.js:10)
onfocusout @ 1:111
Af @ VM651 ej2.min.js:10
t.blurHandler @ VM651 ej2.min.js:10
1:260 <textarea onfocusout=​"ControlId3()​" id=​"ControlId3" data-val=​"true" name=​"ProcessFields[3]​.HTMLStringValue" ejs-for=​"true" class=​"e-rte-hidden">​</textarea>​
```

Finally, found why but I still don't understand. I used the tool that Phil showed and copied the whole page in and removed slowly everything. It works as soon as I remove the  tag. Why is that? And why is only the text input not working with the form tag while the others work with the form tag. And finally, how can I make the input text work with the form tag?

I also tried it with Phil his code and add the form and it doesn't work there either:

```
 <form method="post"><input 
  onfocusout="ControlId1()" 
  id="ControlId1" 
  data-val="true" 
  name="ProcessFields[0].StringValue" 
  ejs-for="true" 
  class="e-control e-textbox e-lib e-input" 
  type="text"
  role="textbox"
  value=""
> </form>
<div class="bg-danger" style="display:none" id="ControlIdWarningId1">a</div>
```

Thus, any suggestions how to make the input tag with onfocusout work within a tag?

Comment: Where is your element with `id="ControlIdWarningId1"`?

Comment: Where is this element in your example? `id="ControlIdWarningId32"`?

Comment: Forgot to add them in the description. Added them now.

Comment: Works fine here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/h2m7x6yv/. Do you see any errors in your browser's dev-tools console?

Comment: Hi Phil, updated the information. Not sure why I get these messages.

Comment: According to your error message, we couldn't find out the reason why this js failed directly. If possible, please share the codes which is related with this issue or created a new project which could reproduce this issue and put it on github for us to reproduce this issue. Notice, please not add any personal information in it.

Comment: Just updated the content with my new findings (understand what the issue is but don't know how to solve it).